# Tracking rectangles with opencv

Tags: object, opencv, tracking

I want to define the orientation and location of the rectangle from web-camera. I used the algorithm camshift, but it gave poor results (high dependence on lighting). Tell my what mechanisms exist to solve this problem. May be exits some source code with similar program?

Answer (score 0):

That only an idea.

I usually think of discrimination to separate the object I want to detect/track. I know you can detect rectangles using other methods.

I prefer to obtain a binarize image that only my object, or a few of them including my target object include.

After that work with blobs. I use cvBlobs library and have option to track blobs and detect blobs. In this library the is a method to obtain angle (orientation), you can try this option.

```
 double cvAngle(CvBlob *blob);
```

If your rectangles is moving try to detect it using difference between frames.

Sory for this long speech.
I wish this could help you.
Jorge

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure what "Rectangle" your talking about, some screenshots or a better description would be great:

1: If you have problems with lightning, you should consider developing your own algorithms to neutralize noise, by converting your image to a binary image and do background substraction (depending on setup, and initialization), erode and dilate etc, though thats another long topic which is worth researching on.

2: What you can do is first you will find all the contours around your rectangle, this can be done with the OpenCV function [findContours();](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=findcontour#findcontours) (Remember you image MUST be binary)
When stored all your contour points, you can afterwards feed the information to another OpenCV function [minAreaRect();](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=findcontour#minarearect)

Store the information from minAreaRect(), which is a struct of the type [RotatedRect](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html?highlight=rotatedrect#rotatedrect); within a variable, and dive into the struct to extract the rotation degree with:

variablename.degree

Answer (score 0):

There is good workable algoritm in sample, OpenCV folder = square.cpp. Need small remake (int main) for video (CvCapture) except image. It works ok.